# Concurrency - how to make it optimal?

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, concurrency

I have a simple program that searches for specific text fragment inside files from local directory. To make it run faster I have used concurrency (inspired by producer-consumer pattern from "Java Concurrency in Practice" book). So this is how it looks:

Main class:

```
public class Application {

    private final BlockingQueue<File> fileBlockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(50000);
    private final FileFilter fileFilter = (path) -> true;
    private static final int CONSUMERS_COUNT = 1;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        application.run();
    }

    private void run() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60);
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }).start();
        startDirectoryCrawlers();
        startFileQueueConsumers();
    }

    private void startDirectoryCrawlers() {
        File C = new File("C://test");
        new Thread(new DirectoryCrawler(fileBlockingQueue, C, fileFilter)).start();
    }

    private void startFileQueueConsumers() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= CONSUMERS_COUNT; i++) {
            new Thread(new FileConsumer(fileBlockingQueue)).start();
        }
    }
}
```

A directory crawler:

```
public class DirectoryCrawler implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<File> fileQueue;
    private final FileFilter fileFilter;
    private final File startingDirectory;


    public DirectoryCrawler(BlockingQueue<File> fileQueue, File startingDirectory, FileFilter fileFilter) {
        this.fileQueue = fileQueue;
        this.startingDirectory = startingDirectory;
        this.fileFilter = fileFilter;
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private void crawl(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] innerFiles = file.listFiles(fileFilter);
            if (innerFiles == null || innerFiles.length == 0) return;
            for (File innerFile : innerFiles) {
                crawl(innerFile);
            }
        } else {
            fileQueue.put(file);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        crawl(startingDirectory);
    }
}
```

File consumer:

```
public class FileConsumer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<File> fileQueue;
    private int counter;

    public FileConsumer(BlockingQueue<File> fileQueue) {
        this.fileQueue = fileQueue;
    }

    private void checkFile(File file) {
        counter++;
        List<String> lines = readFileLines(file);
        if (lines == null) return;
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (line.contains("Some example text")) {
                System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has found matching file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private List<String> readFileLines(File file) {
        try {
            return Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public void run() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has indexed: " + counter);
        }));
        while (true) {
            File top = fileQueue.take();
            checkFile(top);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine, but i wanted to measure how it behaves with different amount of `FileConsumer` threads runnining. For test directory i have used 500 000 txt files with one random line of length 10000. My idea was to let it run for 60 seconds and count how many files were checked by each thread and then sum it up. So each run with different threads amount I was going through the same files. Results are like this:

```
1 thread(s)    | files indexed: 20079 
2 thread(s)    | files indexed: 45704 
4 thread(s)    | files indexed: 90778 
8 thread(s)    | files indexed: 104759 
16 thread(s)   | files indexed: 140464 
32 thread(s)   | files indexed: 145484 
48 thread(s)   | files indexed: 140655 
64 thread(s)   | files indexed: 160161 
72 thread(s)   | files indexed: 131543 
88 thread(s)   | files indexed: 122470 
100 thread(s)  | files indexed: 66816 
128 thread(s)  | files indexed: 96787 
256 thread(s)  | files indexed: 96263 
1024 thread(s) | files indexed: 60076
```

It looks like most optimal would be to use 64 threads, but why is that? How could I know this before I started brute force testing? I would assume that after having more than 64 threads the overhead of creating them and internal synchornization of `LinkedBlockingQueue` makes the whole thing choke.

Is there a connection between that and a processor that I have in my laptop? If I would had like 16 cores instead of 4, would that translate to better performance with more than 64 threads?

Also it seems that this code likes when there are 2^n threads, is it a good practise to use 2^n when it comes to the number of threads?

Comment: I suspect the answer depends a lot on a.) the OS you use, b.) the filesystem you crawl, c.) whether or not various caches are filled, d.) how many cores/threads your laptop has. Also note that a `System.out.println` in a benchmark can easily twist the results, as it's a synchronization point that's often not expected.

Comment: An additonal note which probably doesn't matters for the benchmark, but would matter in the real world is that you always read all lines of the input, even if the first (for example) contains the search pattern. If you expect the search pattern to be very rare, that might be fine, but could also be worth optimizing.

Comment: Also, consider using ThreadPools. Creating and cleaning up threads has an overhead that in your case isn't required. `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` is also a good starting point to experiment with. But there's no perfect answer to say how many threads you should assign to your pools.

Comment: Joachim, Thank you for the comments. So there is no simple anwser for this topic, I know that printing works as synchronization point but that didn't play a role in those benchmarks. And course you are right about reading all lines is not optimal, that is a good point.  

peterulb, didn't think about thread pools, will look into that. Thanks

Comment: I would also include a base line performance comparison with e.g. grep. Perhaps it is just better to make a call to grep instead of trying to invent everything.

Comment: Don’t do things like `catch (Exception ignored) { return null; }`. Further, if you care for performance, don’t read entire files into the memory like `Files.readAllLines(…)`. You can simply use something like `Files.lines(…).anyMatch(line -> line.contains("Some example text"))` to keep only a line at a time in memory and stop at the first match. (But add the `try(…)` to close the stream). And use NIO consistently. There’s no need to mix it with the old `java.io.File` API.

Comment: Your observations on optimal threads will change depending on the operation / os / cores. For example on my 4-core machine your program processes most files with just one thread, yet if I switch the file scan to use NIO `Files.find`, use of 4 threads is optimum (and x3 more files are processed).